# There's no cardinal $\kappa$ such that $2^\kappa = \aleph_0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

I am trying to prove that there is no cardinal $\kappa$ such that  $2^\kappa  = \aleph_0$ .

**My attempt:** We suppose it exists.
Since  $\kappa<2^\kappa$, in particular, $\kappa<\aleph_0$. But that implies that $\kappa$ is finite. And therefore, $2^\kappa$ is finite. That leads to a contradiction.

It doesn't seem to be right, but I don't know how to proceed. Can someone help me?

Comment: it looks just fine and complete to me. +1

Comment: The argument is correct.

Comment: I suggest you look up  "Ordinals".  Set theorists often use the finite ordinals, (which are all cardinals), to be synonymous with natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine.Since Aleph-0 is defined to be the leasr infnite cardinal,anythung less is finite.And if n is finite,so is $2^n$.

Comment: $\aleph_0$ is not defined that way. We can prove it has this property, at the cost of using the axiom of choice, which really has nothing to do with the question. Without choice, the argument needs a bit more, namely the (elementary) proof that if $ k <\aleph_0$, then $ k $ is finite.